# Parse through xml string using JS

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an XML string  in which `Val.responseText` gives me

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <FieldID>21</FieldID>
    <TableName>F003v001</TableName>
    <FieldName>Grade</FieldName>
    <DisplayField>Grade</DisplayField>
    <FieldType>text</FieldType>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

I'm calling `FillTable(sVal.responseXML.documentElement);`

```
function FillTable(sResponse) {

    var preXML = sResponse;

    // code for IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var doc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        doc.async = "false";
        doc.loadXML(preXML);
    }
    // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(preXML, "text/xml");
    }

    // documentElement always represents the root node
    var x = doc.documentElement;

}
```

Now I want to parse through each of the node and populate a datagrid. Can anyone help me parse through the nodes?

How do i get the values for `fieldid`, `tablename`, `displayfield`?

I tried `NodeList = doc.documentElement.selectNodes("Table")` but `nodelist.length` gives me zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/dom_methods.asp

use the doc variable you created, instead of the documentElement, then you can use these methods on it.

Answer (score 1):

You muight find this helpful also:

http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/javascript-parsing-xml-in-javascript